# Deserialize JSON string into a C# complex class object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

If the class consists of simple JSON-compatible types, `MyClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(JSONtext);`
does the job quite nicely. If `MyClass` contains `enum` or `struct` properties, the `DeserializeObject<>` method returns null. I'm currently iterating through the JSON response deserialized into a JObject, assigning values to the inner class created, and returning it. Is there a better way to deserialize the JSON string into an heterogeneous class object?

```
class MyClass
{
    public Int32 wishlistID;
    public Basket currentBasket; //struct
    public List<Int32> items;
    public dStatus _dStatus; //enum
}
```

**Edit**: turns out that, *for some reason*, all `Basket`'s properties had the `private` modifier; of course they couldn't be accessed and result to be therefore `null`. Switching it to `public` did the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your members have to be `public` in order for this to work.

This **doesn't** work:

```
public class MyClass
{
    Int32 a;
    string b; //struct
}

string json = "{ a: 7, b:'abc' }";
MyClass cc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

This **does** work:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Int32 a;
    public string b; //struct
}

string json = "{ a: 7, b:'abc' }";
MyClass cc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

**Edit:**

So after we got through that public stuff you claim that structs\enums **don't** pass.
 Here's and example that they **do**:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Int32 a;
    public test b;
    public eMyEnum c;
}

public struct test
{
    public string str;
}

public enum eMyEnum
{
    A = 0,
    B
}

string json = "{ a: 7, b: {str:'str'}, c: 'B' }";
MyClass cc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

Comment: Edited, forgot to put the `public` modifiers, thanks!

Comment: As for the `b` property though, if it was to be a `Basket` struct, the method would still return null.

Comment: @ShinyPhoenix - I've edited and added an example that structs\enums work. Please provide some more info so we can spot your bug.

Comment: Argh, they do indeed! For some reason - _can't realize what I was thinking at the time I wrote the code_ - all the `struct`'s properties were private! Switching them to `public` did the trick. Thank you!